# How can i remove post type archive URL?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, archives

I am trying to disable portfolio archive link form a post type.
Beacuse my most important page shares the same url with my archive. 
And its wont let my actual page link working.

How can i fix this?

edit: i have page a called "urunler" which lists all my portfolio and shares the same url with my portfolio archive. and when i click link from post's breadcumbs it redirects my to portfolio archive instead of the actual page a designed and linked same url as "/urunler". 
both link shares "/urunler" url
my portfolio name is also urunler and it needs to be stay like that.
just need to delete portfolio items's archive and it's url

[image]

Comment: Have you considered removing your page and using the archives template instead to display the things you want? Can you provide more information too? It isn't clear if this is a custom post or not, or what your page does

Comment: i have page called "products" and it list all my portfolio. and when i click products from post's breadcumb it redirects my to portfolio archive instead of the page linked same way

Comment: So you implemented a page template that acts as a portfolio archive, and put it at the same URL as the portfolio post type archive? Is there a specific reason you didn't just use the `archive-urunler.php` template?

Comment: http://www.ekn.sinankarabulut.com/urunler/  this link is going to portfolio archive. but it should go to a static page.  let me clearify some points; in my theme settings my portfolio slug is "urunler" and it has to stay like that.. and also, i do have a page which i created from my page builder and i need to make its url  "urunler" too. i think my portfolio slug "urunler" overwrites my page url "example.com/urunler/" and that makes this url to lead portfolio archive.